# How to write the stack file for Docker Cloud?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-stack

My main goal is to deploy my **Laravel 5.1** site into my `docker cloud` with via `docker stack`.

- I already connect my DockerCloud account with my AWS account.
- I already have :

  1. docker-compose.yml
  2. app.dockerfile
  3. web.dockerfile

---

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
# The Application
app:
  build:
    context: ./
    dockerfile: app.dockerfile
  working_dir: /var/www
  volumes:
    - ./:/var/www
  environment:
    - "DB_PORT=3306"
    - "DB_HOST=45.55.88.57"

# The Web Server
web:
  build:
    context: ./
    dockerfile: web.dockerfile
  working_dir: /var/www
  volumes_from:
    - app
  ports:
    - 85:80
volumes:
dbdata:
```

---

**app.dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7.0.4-fpm
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev \
      mysql-client libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends \
      && pecl install imagick \
      && docker-php-ext-enable imagick \
      && docker-php-ext-install mcrypt pdo_mysql
```

---

**web.dockerfile**

```
  FROM nginx:1.10
  ADD vhost.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

---

**vhost.conf**

```
 server {
      listen 80;
      index index.php index.html;
      root /var/www/public;

      location / {
          try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
      }

      location ~ \.php$ {
          fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
          fastcgi_pass app:9000;
          fastcgi_index index.php;
          include fastcgi_params;
          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
          fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
      }
  }
```

---

## Result

[image]

`http://localhost:85`

It is working **perfectly** fine on local.

[image]

## Goal

[image]

With all the docker files I got, how do I write the stack file for Docker Cloud ?

Answer (score 0):

I would try Elastic Beanstalk. Please look [here](http://blog.digitopia.com/elastic-beanstalk-docker-deployment/). So you need to rework docker-compose.yml to Dockerrun.aws.json.